# How to get first and last row for every column

Tags: mysql

input

```
DATE    TRANSACTION    TYPE
may01      22           ATM
jun18      34           ATM
Aug14      38           NB
jul18      46           NB
Sep11      29           NB
Dec21      70           NB
jan02      46           MobileB
Jun19      20           MobileB
Sep13      81           MobileB
```

HOW TO GET FIRST AND LAST ROW FOR EACH COLUMN LIKE

```
TYPE        Start_DATE   End_DATE
ATM          may01       jun18
NB           Aug14       Dec21
MobileB      jan02       Sep13
```

IN this output have to get first date and last date group by TYPE.PLEASE HELP ME

Answer (score 1):

Before you massively overhauled your question, I would have suggested:

```
SELECT 'COL1' AS `COL_NAMES`,(SELECT `c1` as `START_ROW` FROM `tbl` WHERE !ISNULL(`c1`) ORDER BY c1 ASC LIMIT 1) AS `ROW_START`,(SELECT `c1` as `END_ROW` FROM `tbl` WHERE !ISNULL(`c1`) ORDER BY c1 DESC LIMIT 1) AS `ROW_END`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'COL2' AS `COL_NAMES`,(SELECT `c2` as `START_ROW` FROM `tbl` WHERE !ISNULL(`c2`) ORDER BY c2 ASC LIMIT 1) AS `ROW_START`,(SELECT `c2` as `END_ROW` FROM `tbl` WHERE !ISNULL(`c2`) ORDER BY c2 DESC LIMIT 1) AS `ROW_END`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'COL3' AS `COL_NAMES`,(SELECT `c3` as `START_ROW` FROM `tbl` WHERE !ISNULL(`c3`) ORDER BY c3 ASC LIMIT 1) AS `ROW_START`,(SELECT `c3` as `END_ROW` FROM `tbl` WHERE !ISNULL(`c3`) ORDER BY c3 DESC LIMIT 1) AS `ROW_END`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'COL4' AS `COL_NAMES`,(SELECT `c4` as `START_ROW` FROM `tbl` WHERE !ISNULL(`c4`) ORDER BY c4 ASC LIMIT 1) AS `ROW_START`,(SELECT `c4` as `END_ROW` FROM `tbl` WHERE !ISNULL(`c4`) ORDER BY c4 DESC LIMIT 1) AS `ROW_END`
```

Assuming a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
  `c1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `tbl` (`c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `c4`) VALUES
(1, 30, 89, 34),
(2, 49, 76, 44),
(NULL, 52, 90, NULL),
(NULL, NULL, 16, NULL);
```

I can't give you an exact answer, now, with your new data, now, but my answer here should bring you pretty close, you'd just need to fix a few things like the column names, the table name.  My `!ISNULL(...)` logic is fine if you're testing for the first and last non-`NULL` values, which includes the empty string. If you're testing for the empty string instead, use `LENGTH(...)=0` instead, or a combination if both are possible: `(!ISNULL(...) AND LENGTH(...)>0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get the first and last rows like below

```
select type,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(date AS CHAR) ORDER BY date), ',', 1 ) as Start_date,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(date AS CHAR) ORDER BY date DESC), ',', 1 ) as End_date
from test
group by type;
```

Check [**SQL Fiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9d52/3) here.

Comment: Glad i helped...Kindly Accept the answer if it helped you, so that it will be useful for other :)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL there is predefined functions for fetching the First and last row records based on column names

```
SELECT FIRST(column_name) FROM table_name;
SELECT LAST(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

In MySQL

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name ASC
LIMIT 1;



 SELECT column_name FROM table_name
    ORDER BY column_name DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: is this function really works or available  in mysql?? n if yes then in which version of mysql??

Comment: Above will work in SQL. IF you want to MySQL                                                                                                                        SELECT column_name FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name ASC
LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 0):

the below code works fine , first i have converted date in to date format 
select *,str_to_date(date,"%m/%d/%Y " ) as dat from tab3 ;

SELECT TYPE,MIN(DAT) AS SD,MAX(DAT) AS ED FROM A GROUP BY TYPE;

Answer (score 0):

```
select
*
from
(select * from application, (SELECT @rownums:=0) r order by  (@rownum := @rownum + 1) asc limit 1) a1

union

select
*
from
(select * from application, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r1 order by  (@rownum := @rownum + 1) desc limit 1) a2;
```